# How to make session variables available as Twig globals?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

Within a twig view, it's possible to get a session variable with

```
{% set myVar=app.session.get('myVar') %}
```

It's handy, but I need to do it each time I use a view that doesn't extends base template.

Instead, I would like to set those sessions variables, as twig globals.

I tried to use `@session` in `config/packages/twig.yaml`, under `globals`, but beside `@session.storage`, I can't find any methods to access my variables.

I thought about doing it in my `kernelListener` event, but I don't know which service to import to add some dynamics twig globals (if it's even possible).

Comment: The long solution is below, a simple solution is to do what you have in your wrapper (`base.html.twig`) template. This should carry it all the way down in whatever extends it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom extension is the way to go. Descriptive, easy to test. No need to call an event listener when not using Twig.

My solution uses [lazy Twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#creating-lazy-loaded-twig-extensions) which are available since Twig 1.35 and 2.4.4

Both will autowire and autoconfigure:

```
final class SessionRuntime implements RuntimeExtensionInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function get(string $id, $default = null)
    {
        return $this->session->get($id, $default);
    }
}

final class SessionExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('from_session', [SessionRuntime::class, 'get']),
        ];
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('from_session', [SessionRuntime::class, 'get']),
        ];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Hello {{ 'name'|from_session }}. Last visit: {{ 'last_visit'|from_session('never') }}
```

Or:

```
Hello {{ from_session('name') }}
```

If you are really so strongly after globals, instead create custom service and bind it to the `session` global variable, eg:

```
globals:
    session: `@App\Twig\Runtime\SessionRuntime`


class SessionRuntime
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function __call(string $key, array $params = [])
    {
        return $this->session->get($key);
    }
}
```

and in Twig:

```
{{ session.yourSessionKey }}
```

Comment: I'm not looking into how to add a new `TwigFilter`, but how to set dynamic globales for all twig view. I found my answer, I will post it

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution.
I had to inject `Twig\Environment` within my kernelListener class

```
use Twig\Environment as TwigEnvironment;

class kernelListener {
    private $twigEnvironment;

    public function __construct(TwigEnvironment $twigEnvironment,) {
        $this->twigEnvironment=$twigEnvironment;
    }

    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event) {
        $myGlobalValue='someValue';

        /** @var Session $session */
        $session=$event->getRequest()->getSession();
        $session->set('myGlobalValue', $myGlobalValue)


        $this->twigEnvironment->addGlobal('myGlobalValue', $myGlobalValue);
    }
}
```

With this, `twigGobalName` can be accessed in all twig views.

Did valid Emix answer as it's not wrong either.
Just a constrain on my end make my own answer fit my needs

Comment: This is a poor's man solution. I'd vote against it. You basically initialize a session for every request. Is it really so hard to do something well, just to save couple of characters in the code? Eg. just to write `myGlobalName` instead of `getMyGlobalName()` ?

Comment: @emix I don't initialize a session for every request, I use current available session. And I don't see how "poor" this solution is. My goal is to generate twig gobals like ones you would write in `config/packages/twig.yaml`. The different is that they got dynamic values as they're generated when calling `onKernelController()`. I don't say that your solution isn't valid. Just not my needs. I generate data when calling `onKernelController`, why go the extra length to make a `TwigFilter` when I can directly set a twig global?

Comment: @Preciel you kinda do initialize the `session` on each request with your solution, whereas with @emix's answer the `session` only get initialized when needed, thus increasing the performance of the script. But if you aren't worried about the performance your solution is valid

Comment: @DarkBee how do I initialise the session when I'm already at `onKernelController`? Symfony already initialised it at this point. Either way, I do need to save those value into the session as I also use some of them in controllers. If there is a way to set a global variable for controllers without using session, I would love to know it. Would be really helpful.

Comment: Symfony doesn't start session until it is accessed for the first time. I'm just curious why you are so strongly after globals?

Comment: @emix while some values are both in session and globals, some are not in session at all. But in need them anyway in my twig views

Comment: @Preciel because the `kernel.controller` is being sent at every request? Even on requests where you don't need session data

Comment: @DarkBee yes, everything I put in `onKernelController`, I need it at each request. It hold values about language, timezone, user preferences, etc

Comment: Still, it's a poor's man solution. I've updated my answer. There may be times when you don't use Twig (eg. sub requests, REST api calls etc.)

Comment: Funnily enough, I had posted an answer with this solution, but deleted it when I saw emix answer. Maybe I should undelete it?

Comment: Won't be needed @yivi thanks though... emix isn't wrong at all. It's just the current project constrains (It not a new app)